# Play framework 2.5 not compiling source files (inside app folder)

Tags: playframework-2.5

We have a Play project with folder structure given in the link https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anatomy.

We have `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.2")` in `plugins.sbt` and in `build.sbt` we have added the below lines,

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

While we give `compile` command (through activator), the project loads the dependency jars from `build.sbt`, but the `.classes` files are not generated in target folder.

Could anyone please help us in solving the issue?

Comment: Did you create the project using activator, or have you assembled it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

We have solved the issue by adding the following line to build.sbt file,

javaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "app"

After the addition of this, the .java files and .scala files inside the "app" folder gets compiled.